# Setuptools pip failed with error code 1 when installing Hue browser for Apache Hadoop

Tags: python, pip, hue

I'm trying to install Hue browser for Apache Hadoop on my mac. So I retrieve the git folder :

```
git clone https://github.com/cloudera/hue.git
```

I followed this tutorial [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/04/how-to-install-hue-on-a-mac/)

But when doing `make apps` I end up with the following error :

```
python2.7 /Users/leo/Downloads/hue-3.8.1/tools/virtual-bootstrap/virtual-bootstrap.py \
    -qq --no-site-packages /Users/leo/Downloads/hue-3.8.1/build/env
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/leo/Downloads/hue-3.8.1/tools/virtual-bootstrap/virtual-bootstrap.py", line 2355, in <module>
main()
File "/Users/leo/Downloads/hue-3.8.1/tools/virtual-bootstrap/virtual-bootstrap.py", line 827, in main
symlink=options.symlink)
File "/Users/leo/Downloads/hue-3.8.1/tools/virtual-bootstrap/virtual-bootstrap.py", line 995, in create_environment
install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
File "/Users/leo/Downloads/hue-3.8.1/tools/virtual-bootstrap/virtual-bootstrap.py", line 963, in install_wheel
'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
File "/Users/leo/Downloads/hue-3.8.1/tools/virtual-bootstrap/virtual-bootstrap.py", line 905, in call_subprocess
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/leo/Downloads...ld/env/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

I don't understand what the problem is. Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Are you using Hue from master or 3.8.1? On master it should be 3.9 and should not have this problem

Comment: Hi. I use 3.9.0 version and still running into this error

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo make apps`

it works for me on Sierra.